# UITableview mixes up cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i have a problem with my `UITableview`. After scrolling or pushing the switch it starts sometimes mixing up the cells. So you can so the text of one cell shows up in the other. I read a lot about tableViews, but I found nothing that fits for my code.
Here it is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Course:",@"Course Section");
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = entryTableCourseName;

        }

       else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Due Date:";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = entryTableDueDateString;            }
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            //cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Title", @"entryTableTaskTitle");
            [cell.contentView addSubview:nameField];

        }

        else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:TaskView];
        }

    }


    else if (indexPath.section == 2) {

        if (entryTableGradeSwitch.on) {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Grading", @"GradingCell");
                cell.accessoryView = entryTableGradeSwitch;
            }
            else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Options", @"GradingCellOptions");
            }
        }
        else {
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Grading", @"GradingCell");
            cell.accessoryView = entryTableGradeSwitch;
        }
    }

}
```

I feel like I'm doing something really wrong on setting up the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all due to cell-reusability. There are plenty of posts about this on StackOverflow, and I would recommend that you search for "UITableViewCell Reusability Problems", and you will come across the solution.

In short .. What happens here is that when you are scrolling, the cell essentially re-uses the one used before at that indexPath, and cellForRowAtIndexPath assigns a different cell at that indexpath.

***Solution ?***

1. Use different reuse identifiers for each cell.
2. Subclass your tableViewCell with the view or label that is getting messed up.

Comment: I thought about using different identifiers, but I read that it's not good to do it. How can I do it properly? Individual "name" for each cell or with a Variable in the Name depending on indexPath

Comment: individual name for each cell would be good. or you can also assign the same identifier for a section. its upto you.

Comment: Just to clearify my confusion. I thought The indexPath is a static thing. So each cell has always the Same. Is that wrong?

Comment: Well. Lets put it this way. Your screen has 8 cells, and you have lets say 100 rows in your tableView. If you were to scroll to the last 8 rows in your tableView (92-100), they will have index path of 0-7, and not (92-100)

Comment: @Legolas - what? Cells don't have an index path property, but when scrolling, the data source will be asked for the cells for indexes 92 -100 in that situation.

Comment: @jrturton Yes thats right ! In that case - "visually" it will still be using cells 1-8.

Comment: Okay I think I understand whats messing it up but After a Lot of reading I still don't know how to Set up a proper cellIdentifier. I think I should create one for the taskView cell and so on - but how(without index path) and where?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you implement

```
- (void) prepareForReuse
```

in your cell if you reuse them. In this routine clean up anything you added to the cell that you don't want to show up in another reuse. If you don't add any custom items just make sure when you populate a cell that you set everything even if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do this:

```
 [cell.contentView addSubview:TaskView]
```

Or something like it, you are adding a new subview to the cell. As the cells get reused, you add more and more subviews.

From your code, it isn't even clear where nameView and taskView come from. They should be either added once when a cell is first created, and just configured thereafter, or they should be part of your cell as designed in the xib or storyboard.

Comment: Should I add them in the if (cell=nill) ?

Comment: Yes. Are you using storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super-simple fix for this, and you still get to keep your reuse-identifiers! Also no subclassing or anything needed.

It's simple: just make sure and set ***all*** of your labels and views. This means that if one cell isn't going to use the detail text label, **still** set it to `@""`. By doing this, you make sure that no leftover data from the content that used the cell before is still there.

Super simple, and works every time! Also way better resource wise than not reusing your cells.